# ¿Cómo configurar Vite para que transpile a la carpeta de distribución un archivo .gltf?

Tags: vite

Estoy creando mi portfolio con React y Vite, en el cuál he subido un componente en 3D e hice el deploy en la página de Vercel.

El problema está en que al momento de transpilar el sitio a la carpeta de distribución, para hacer el deploy, no me incluye el archivo gltf que necesito para crear el componente 3D y por ende me arroja un error 404.

Intenté buscando en su documentación y encontré una opción llamada [assetsInclude](https://vitejs.dev/config/#assetsinclude) pero, de igual manera, no funciona.

¿Alguien sabría cómo podría solucionar esto?

Dejo el código de configuración de Vite.

```
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 2500,
    manifest: true,
  },
  assetsInclude: "./grogu.gltf",
});
```

También dejo el link de mi repositorio por si se necesite indagar más en el código.
https://github.com/Calvarenga96/portfolio

Comment: ¿Y si colocás corchetes al string? Es decir, `assetsInclude: ["**/grogu.gltf"]`. O como dice la documentación, `assetsInclude: ['**/*.gltf']` (aunque veo que en tu repo está de esa manera).

Comment: @padaleiana Acabo de intentar de la manera que comentaste pero, lastimosamente no funcionó.